# overriding Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Tag_Relation

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides

I need to override `Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Tag_Relation` for a site I'm working on.

I have already created my class that extends `Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Tag_Relation`:

```
class Web_Core_Model_Tag_Resource_Tag_Relation extends Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Tag_Relation
{
    public function loadByTagCustomer($model)
    {
    [...]
    }
}
```

And placed that in the file `app/code/local/Web/Core/Model/Tag/Resource/Tag/Relation.php`

In the module's config.xml (which is activated, since there are other parts of the module that are working, I added:

```
<global>
  <models>
    <core>
      <rewrite>
       <mage_tag_model_resource_tag_relation>
        Web_Core_Model_Tag_Resource_Tag_Relation
       </mage_tag_model_resource_tag_relation>
     </rewrite>
    </core>
 </models>
</global>
```

I'm guessing this is wrong, since it is not working... How should I declare the overriding in my config.xml? Am I in the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not rewrite resource class  in proper method and did not follow up magento resource model class  format that why it does not  override properly.

**Basic format of overwrite a resource class is**

```
   <models>
        <rewriteableModuleResourceClassIndenfiter>
            <rewrite>
                <Rest_Of_ClassName_Of_Resource_class>Your_Write_Class_Name</Rest_Of_ClassName_Of_Resource_class>
            </rewrite>
        </<rewriteableModuleResourceClassIndenfiter>
    </models>
```

### Brief:

As per as ,magento  [*`tag_resource`*](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/etc/config.xml#L38)  is resource type of magento Mage_Tage module,which prefix class  is `Mage_Tag_Model_Resource`

See  at [config.xml](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/etc/config.xml#L45) of Mage_Tag Module

```
 <tag_resource>
                <class>Mage_Tag_Model_Resource</class>
```

***You modified code:***

```
<models>
    <tag_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <tag_relation>Web_Core_Model_Tag_Resource_Tag_Relation</tag_relation>
        </rewrite>
    </tag_resource>
</models>
```